# pass session variable from one web application to another when login

Tags: session

i want to pass my session value from one application to another on IIS sever. using ASP.NET.. 
 when user login the page will redirect to other application..
i want to show information on that user from database and login that user on other application page

Comment: So whats the problem ? Where is your code.

Comment: sir i have no problem with my code.. i still write the script for this.. i just want to pass session value to another application.. i mean login page is another application and show details are on another application

Comment: But firstly you need to show the code that you have tryed to achieve this task, then only someone can help you. [See how to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Session information is unique to each application. So if you want to pass the information to another application then you need to pass it as part of the URL.

So say I am logging into:

http://appA.me.com

then you would redirect the user to:

http://appB.com?token=aksjhaskduwiwiwwuwuw

The value of token is then pulled apart in appB and you log the user in or whatever assuming the information in the token is valid.

Obviously the token you pass needs to be non reversible (so encrypt and hash it) and unique each time it is generated, otherwise someone could take this and masquerade as that user.

Comment: sir would you please give me the understand able example.